# Tkinter me abre muchas veces el mismo archivo txt seleccionado

Tags: python, tkinter, archivo

[image: Abre demasiadas veces el mismo archivo]

codigo el cual se encargar de abrir el archivo, en tkinter tiene un boton que llama a la funcion ReproducirEscritorio pero cuando lo ejecuto para llamar un archivo .txt u otro archivo se abre demasiadas veces.

pero antes de esta funcion hay otra la cual permite ver un listado completo de todos los archivos y los almacena en una listbox

```
def ReproducirEscritorio():
    #engine.say("Abriendo Directorio")
    #engine.runAndWait()
    #lstMaterias.delete(0,END)
    home = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
    carpetas = os.listdir(home)
    ruta = home + "\\Desktop"
    archivos = os.listdir(ruta)
    try:
        for i in range(len(archivos)):


            #print(str(i) + ')' + str(archivos[i]))
            ejecutar = ruta + '\\' + archivos[int(entrada.get())]
            #justo en estas lineas hace que el archivo se ejecute varias veces y no solo una        
            os.startfile(ejecutar)

    except:
        engine.say("Error, esta fuera de las opciones")
        engine.runAndWait()
        MessageBox.showinfo("Aviso de actividad ","Opción fuera de rango")
```

Comment: Hola, Álex. Bienvenido a Stack overflow en español. Parece que le estás asignando el mismo valor a la variable ejecutar, cada elemento que recorre el bucle te va a llamar startfile con la variable ejecutar seteada al mismo valor.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, podrías guiarme de como solucionar ese problema, y me podrías explicar sobre asignar  el valor, como hago para ejecutar una vez ?

Comment: Si pudiste solucionar tu problema, añade una respuesta con ella: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: El problema de abrir muchas veces el mismo archivo se soluciona con un break al final para romper el siclo                                                                                          for i in range(len(archivos)):

            ejecutar = ruta + '\\' + archivos[int(entrada.get())]  
            os.startfile(ejecutar)                                                                                   
            break

Comment: si necesitas hacer un break luego de la primera ejecución de un loop... No necesitas el loop...